# angularjs ui-view doesn't work with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a folder structure like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqvvZ.png

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="cartApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="./dashboard/dashboardCtrl.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

the route.js

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider


        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: './dashboard/index.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        });

}]);
```

public/dashboardCtrl.html

```
<div ng-controller="dashboardCtrl as dash">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p>{{dash.something}}</p>
</div>
```

public/dashboardCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', [function() {

    var dash = this;

    dash.something = "something";
}]);
```

That is it. I've no clue where is the mistake is, everything seems just fine to me. When I load http://localhost:4000/ I couldn't see anything. It's blank.

Comment: remove ./ from templateUrl,  specify the path from root directory

Comment: could you please check your console, you have messed up here `app.config(['$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
` with wrong dependency sequence & injection

Comment: @PankajParkar ah what should it be then?

Comment: @SoniaA. it would be `app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {`

Answer (score 0):

change your route.js file to

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider


        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In route.js you decared module `cartApp`, In dashboard controller again you declared the same module `cartApp`.

So I think problem with your module as you declared same module multiple times.
And check config dependencies order.
Try like this:

route.js

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider''$stateProvider',function($locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider


        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: './dashboard/index.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        });

}]);
```

dashboard.js:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', [function() {

    var dash = this;

    dash.something = "something";
}]);
```